# Symbols unable to be loaded when remote debugging a C# program

Tags: c#, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

I created a "Hello World" program in C#, and placed it on a remote server to test out remote debugging. I copied both the *.exe and *.pdb files and placed it in the same folder on the remote server, and ran msvsmon.exe with no authentication.

I ran the application on the remote server, and using visual studio 2005 on my local computer, attached to the binary for debugging. However after attaching I found that the breakpoints I set would not be hit. In the modules window, it showed that the symbols for my application were not loaded. When I manually loaded them, it said the symbols did not match the application, when in fact they were both built at the same time.

I may be missing out something here, but I did the same steps with a C++ project and it worked fine. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks.

Edit: If it helps, when I checked the modules window, for my application it said "no native symbols in symbol file" as opposed to "no symbols loaded"

Comment: Do you have "Microsoft Symbol Servers" feature enabled?

Comment: I didn't think you could debug managed code without authentication. Did you choose attach to managed code when you attached the debugger?

Comment: Did you ensure you selected Full-PDB?  If not you can not  attach to a running application to debug.

Comment: Hi MattC, yes my project is using Full-PDB

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links :

[Remote Debugging in Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/04/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

[MSDN UK Screencasts: Visual Studio 2008 - Remote Debugging with MSVSMON.EXE](http://www.developerfusion.com/media/113706/visual-studio-2008-remote-debugging-with-msvsmonexe/)

**EDIT**

[MSDN : Visual Studio 2005 - Remote Debugging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910448)

Comment: Have you got a VS 2005 version of those links :-)